# Drawable View pager indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have this view pager, with an indicator library that draws for me a circle that can be colored (pretty basic), however; I've been searching a lot for a library that allow me to put a drawable instead of the circle (selected and unselected pictures) without succeeding in having a result. Can anyone please help?
(wasn't able to implement Jake Wharton's library because it's in maven not normal gradle dependency)

here's my pager adapter

```
private class NewsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<NewsItem> allNews;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private CustomPagerAdapter imagesPager;

    public NewsPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsItem> allNews) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.allNews = allNews;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allNews.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_pager_item, container, false);
        final WebView detailWebView = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailWebView);
        RelativeLayout pagerlayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pagerlayout);

        final ViewPager pg = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(pager);
        final PageIndicator mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) itemView.findViewById(R.id.indicatorDetailsNews); 
        imagesPager = new CustomPagerAdapter(NewsDetailActivity.this, allNews.get(position));
        pg.setAdapter(imagesPager);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(pg);  


        pg.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                mIndicator.setCurrentItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        detailWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        detailWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<html><head>\n" +
                "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
                "@font-face {\n" +
                "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                "    src: url(\"file:///android_asset/GE_Dinar_Two_Medium.otf\")\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "body {\n" +
                "    font-family: MyFont;\n" +
                "    text-align: justify;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "</style><body dir=\"rtl\">" + allNews.get(position).getDescription() + "</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

        detailWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: thank you for your reply